# Adding a new record to DB, key is always zero

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an existing App written using **Microsoft Visual C++ 2017**, ASP.NET, MVC 5.2.7.0, Entity Framework Version=5, DB is SQL Server. When I add a new record to my DB, the key (ParkID) that results is a zero and when I try and save the change. I get an error.

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ParkID', table 'N_CWBFM-20170818.dbo.Park'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

The database `N_CWBFM-20170818` was downloaded from the HOST where my app runs.

Confession, this is a hobby, so I may not use the correct terminology and translating other ways of adding data to a DB to the method I am using.

**Model**

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace CWBFM.Models
{
    public class Park
    {
        [Key]
        public int ParkID { get; set; }

        public bool ParkChangePending { get; set; }  // change pending true/false
        public int ParkChangeCount { get; set; }     // Count the number of changes to this record
        public int ParkPrevRec { get; set; }         // points backwards to the previous version
        public int ParkNextRec { get; set; }         // ID of previous record 

Omitted
```

**DB Context**

```
using CWBFM.Models;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;

namespace CWBFM.DAL
{
    public class CWBFMContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Park> Parks { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Photo> Photo { get; set; }
        public DbSet<StateFilter> StateFilters { get; set; }
Omitted
```

**Controller**

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using CWBFM.Models;
using CWBFM.DAL;

namespace CWBFM.Controllers
{ 
    public class ParkController : BaseController
    {
        private CWBFMContext db = new CWBFMContext();

Omitted

        // POST: /Park/Create

        [HttpPost]
        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult ParkCreate(Park park)
        {
            setYesNo(); //set the values for the dropdown box (Yes, No, Unknown)

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                park.ParkChangePending = false;
                park.ParkChangeCount = 0;
                park.ParkDateCreated = DateTime.Now;
                park.ParkDateChange = DateTime.Now;
                park.ParkCreatedBy = @User.Identity.Name;
                park.ParkChangedBy = @User.Identity.Name;
                park.ParkStatus = "N";
                db.Parks.Add(park);
                int stop = park.ParkID;
                db.SaveChanges();

                park.ParkRecID = "Park" + park.ParkID.ToString();
                db.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("ParkDetails", new { id=park.ParkID });  
           }

            return View(park);
        }
```

**Config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=152368
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <!-- <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" /> -->

  <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
        <add namespace="Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" maxRequestLength="20971520" />
    <!-- This will handle requests up to 20MB  -->
    <profile inherits="CWBFM.Models.MyUserProfile" defaultProvider="DefaultProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="DefaultProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <!--<profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>-->
    <membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <add connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <!--
            If you are deploying to a cloud environment that has multiple web server instances,
            you should change session state mode from "InProc" to "Custom". In addition,
            change the connection string named "DefaultConnection" to connect to an instance
            of SQL Server (including SQL Azure and SQL  Compact) instead of to SQL Server Express.
      -->
    <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="asset.axd" validate="false" type="Telerik.Web.Mvc.WebAssetHttpHandler, Telerik.Web.Mvc" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="CompilableFileModule" type="SassAndCoffee.CompilableFileModule" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <!-- This will handle requests up to 1024MB (1GB) -->
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="asset" />
      <add name="asset" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="asset.axd" type="Telerik.Web.Mvc.WebAssetHttpHandler, Telerik.Web.Mvc" />
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" /><remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" /><remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" /><add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" /></handlers>
    <modules>
      <remove name="CompilableFileModule" />
      <add name="CompilableFileModule" type="SassAndCoffee.CompilableFileModule" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.7.0" newVersion="5.2.7.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.7.0" newVersion="5.2.7.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
```

It dies on the save (`db.SaveChanges();`). A breakpoint at `int stop = park.ParkID;` shows that the `ParkID` is zero.

```
 ParkID = 0
```

I have looked at several proposed solutions, but just can’t find one that works. Any suggestions. Could I have missed an update in my config when I changed to EF 5?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: SQL Server        <add name="CWBFMContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=N_CWBFM-20170818;Integrated Security=True;User Id=****; Password=*****" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: Is it **really** EF 5 (the "old" classic EF) - or are you talking about EF **Core** 5 for the shiny new .NET 5 ? Please be **precise** about what you're using !! Those are **NOT** the same things - some solutions might work in one case, but not the other.....

Comment: I added part of the config above.   <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>

Comment: I am not sure what this means. Is it correct?  --- targetFramework="4.6.1" (in more than one place)

Comment: 6/27/2014 - v1.0.0.0.0 - Initial Issue (not sure that helps, but the app has been around for awhile.

Comment: OK, this is strange. Looking at an older saved copy of the app from 2017, it appears at one point I went to EF 6. Not sure how or why I am now back on EF 5 (???). Of course, to change back to EF 6, I get error about it not matching the assembly version, but if that sounds like what may be causing the issue, can always do the work to go back to EF 6.

Comment: I have also check the References folder to make sure I had the correct version installed. EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0

Answer (score 0):

This can occur if the database was set up without an Identity column set on the PK, but EF will automatically expect an identity column on keys named "Id" or with the "Id" suffix on the class name. (I.e. Park.ParkId)  If the DB is not actually set up to use an Identity but EF is configured for an Identity column (DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity) the resulting insert statements will *not* include the ParkId column, resulting in a #null failure in the database.

I generally recommend being explicit with configuration rather than relying on EF's conventions for behaviour:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int ParkId { get; set; }
```

If you expect the new records to be given a PK value automatically by the database then update the database schema to mark these PKs as Identity columns. If your schema is code-first and generating Migrations then there should be a way to apply a migration to update the PKs to identity columns. Otherwise simply make the change within SSMS.

If instead you want to provide PKs from your code, (such as part of data imports from other data sources) then you need to configure EF to not treat the PK as an Identity.

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
public int ParkId { get; set; }
```

Comment: I'll give that a try. It was set up as follows: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Park] (
    [ParkID]                 INT             IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,  ---  CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Park] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ParkID] ASC)
);

Comment: I added the [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)], that did not help.

Comment: I also tried [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] - did not help either. I also used MS SQL server to double check that ParkID is identified as the key and set to auto-increment.

Comment: Hmm, Ok 2 possibilities: #1, Identity_insert has been turned on in that table and not turned off again.  Run `GET Identity_Insert Parks`. If set to "ON" then `SET Identity_Insert Parks OFF` and you should be fixed. (check other tables as well) #2 Check your connection string at runtime with a breakpoint and capturing `var conn = db.Database.Connection.ConnectionString` and double-check that matches the database you are verifying against. Sometimes issues come up because the runtime config points at an older DB lacking the schema changes expected. (it happens:)

Comment: Thanks - believe I figured out the problem. When I copied the DB, I did not get the schema copied correctly and the auto-increment did not get turned on. I used MS SQL Server / task /  generate Script (web site) and set it up to drop/alter the table with copy schema and data set. Pointed  the resulting SQL script to my Local version of the DB, executed and it appears to have worked. Well at least died in another place. Need to do the same excise on another table to see if that corrects my problem. Took a while to identify the real issue. Thanks for feed back, pointed in right direction.

Comment: OK, was able to add a new entry in to the Park DB. I'll probably need to check all of the tables in my Db, but I think that got it.